# Is it possible to disable a UISearchController for userinputs?

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, uisearchcontroller

I have this project, where a modal pops up, to filter search results - the `UISearchController` is visible in my navigation bar when the modal pops up. I can't remove it, as it will look weird, as the modal doesn't fill the whole screen. The problem is, that the `UISearchController` is still active when the modal pops up, and if I tap it, it all goes crazy - so I want to disable the input field, but I really can't find out how to :/

So does anyone know, how to disable the input field in the `UISearchController`?

Best regards :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = false
```